# Compiling differences in Visual C++ and *nix environments

Tags: c++, winapi, unix, compilation

Is there a difference between compiling projects in *nix environments and MS Visual C++?
For example, there is a "stdafx.h" file in Visual C++.

The reason I'm asking is that I submitted a piece of code which compiled in g++, to [refactormycode.com](http://refactormycode.com/codes/957-breadth-first-search-textbook-example).  Then after it got a refactoring, it seemed to include a "stdafx.h", so I figured I'll download Visual C++ 2008 Express but I can't seem to get it to build.

What I'm doing is creating a new project > Create a Win32 Console Application, and replacing the auto-generated .cpp with the refactored code. Am I doing something wrong here?

This is the compiler errors I'm getting:

```
------ Build started: Project: bfs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
bfs.cpp
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(3) : error C2871: 'std' : a namespace with this name does not exist
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(8) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(8) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(25) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(26) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(28) : warning C4183: 'getEdges': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(32) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(32) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(12) : error C2758: 'Vertex::Edges' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list
        c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(25) : see declaration of 'Vertex::Edges'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(22) : error C2065: 'm_edges' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(22) : error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(27) : error C2065: 'm_edges' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(38) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(38) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(38) : error C2039: 'iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(38) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(41) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(41) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(83) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(83) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(84) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(86) : warning C4183: 'getVertices': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(89) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_vertices'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(89) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(89) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(43) : error C2758: 'Graph::Vertices' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list
        c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(83) : see declaration of 'Graph::Vertices'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(55) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(55) : error C2228: left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(61) : error C2065: 'VertexIterator' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(61) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iter'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(61) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(62) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(64) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(64) : error C2227: left of '->getId' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(65) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(78) : error C2065: 'VertexIterator' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(78) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iter'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(78) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(79) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(80) : error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(80) : error C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete objects that are not pointers
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(85) : error C2065: 'm_vertices' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(119) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(119) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(119) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(106) : error C2065: 'UINT_MAX' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(138) : error C2065: 'queue' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(138) : error C2059: syntax error : 'const'
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(140) : error C2065: 'Attributes' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(142) : error C2065: 'q' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(142) : error C2228: left of '.push' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(143) : error C2065: 'q' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(143) : error C2228: left of '.empty' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\alg\bfs\bfs\bfs.cpp(143) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\alg\bfs\bfs\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
bfs - 66 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why have you put '*' instead of 'U' in the word 'Unix' ?

Comment: @Kamran: it's a common way to denote "any Unix-derivative" such as Linux, BSD or OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refactored code is missing certain includes. More than likely they are included in the precompiled header, stdafx.h, which usually isn't a good idea. Add the following includes to the bfs.cpp file, in between the "stdafx.h" include and the "using" declaration:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
```

```
Compiling...
bfs - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. The "set" header wasn't included.
Unfortunately, this question has turned more into a "help me debug"-type of question which I didn't intentionally want it to turn into. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below headers in the refactored code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
```

Comment: Looks like the most likely solution.  You can also try just removing the stdafx.h includes and compiling with g++.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual C++ compiler treats include directives for precompiled headers in a special way, and often they are called `stdafx.h`, so I'll describe that treatment and see if that's the issue.

Each file using `stdafx.h` as the precompiled header will have this line at the top.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Normally, this means the compiler looks for `stdafx.h` in the same source folder as the file that included it. However, when `stdafx.h` is the precompiled header, the Visual C++ compiler automatically includes the project's `stdafx.h` precompiled output, regardless of where the `stdafx.h` header or the output is. When the same project is compiled under GCC, GCC won't know where the file is if it's in another folder. You'll have to set the include path of the project appropriately so each preprocessor-related `#include` can find the proper file.

Normally, when an include file is located in an unknown folder specified only by a compiler [`-I`] directive, the include is written as:

```
#include <filename.h>
```

Unfortunately, Visual C++ doesn't let you use this notation for the precompiled header, and you have to rely on GCC following the include paths even for files specified with "" (double quotes). This behavior may or may not be in the C++ standard, but the one thing you'll want to make sure of is you don't have any extra/unintended `stdafx.h` files in the source tree, or you may run into even more unexpected compiled-code differences between VC++ and GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
#include <stdafx.h> // note angle brackets
```

This is different from the page you linked, which looks for stdafx.h in the current directory.

---

Or have you tried replacing that with the #includes in the original file?

Comment: The angled brackets didn't work and neither did my original includes.  It's complaining that it can't even find the std namespace! I've added my compiler errors to the questions. This should make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new project , I recommend this :

New Project-> Empty Project

Then,

Project->Add New Item...-> C++ File (.cpp)

It's different from Win32 Console Application.