# Difference Betwen Visual C++ 2008 And g++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

I'm learning *C++* and when I was testing the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express* and *Eclipse Ganymede*, but with the *g++* compiler as default, I've noted that a same code in *VC++* get some errors and in *g++* compile normally, without errors or warnings and execute normally, but I want to know what is the difference between *VC++* syntax and *g++* syntax? Thanks!

Comment: There's loads of differences, best option (as with most questions) is to post the code and generated errors here.

Comment: @Justile, i want to know the difference in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this to Pavel's answer:

If you are developing a cross platform product, use g++ ([MingW](http://www.mingw.org/)) and stick to the C++ standard. Use POSIX compliant APIs provided by MingW where the standard facilities does not serve the purpose. An executable built using MingW does not need a special runtime to be installed on the target system, but VC++ 2008 requires that. So deployment is simpler with MingW applications.

An advantage of VC++ is its great IDE. The Microsoft compiler seems to perform some Windows specific optimizations as well.

Still, MingW complemented with the [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE can give you a great, free, cross-platform C++ development environment.

Comment: Also the NetBeans IDE give you great development environment.

Comment: It shows something if the Linux compiler is the standard and the Microsoft compiler/IDE is not to be used for cross platform.

Answer (score 13):

Can't comment because I'm new (reputation isn't 50 yet), but here's another Stack Overflow question that deals with a similar topic:

[Compiling differences in Visual C++ and *nix environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150723/compiling-differences-in-visual-c-and-nix-enviroments)

Answer (score 4):

It's a very broad topic. Both compilers are broadly ISO C++ conformant with some exceptions, but those exceptions may differ (for example, VC++ treats `throw` specifier on functions in a non-standard way, while g++ is standard compliant in that regard).  In addition, both compilers provide a fairly large number of extensions, which are mostly mutually incompatible (e.g. VC++ `__property` and `__interface`, or g++ `typeof` and computed goto). In general, the best advice here is to consult the documentation of either product. If you have any *specific* code that you're having problems with, and would like to know why it does compile with one but not the other, then it would be possible to answer in more detail.